# YouTube stalls after 30 seconds on wireless with one laptop but works well on the other

Tags: wireless-networking, youtube

I have recently installed a Netgear DGN1000 wireless router. Since the day I installed, YouTube is stalling after 30 seconds or so on one of my laptops. However, it works perfectly alright on the other laptop. With a wired connection it works alright on both laptops.

Tried uninstalling many programs on the laptop (including antivirus, firewall etc.) but no luck.

1. Yes.  Youtube works fine with one laptop whether it was streaming alone or both laptops are streaming at the same time.  In fact I tried playing the same content at the same time -- streams well in the "good" one and stalls in the other
2. I tried changing channels (again randomly) of the wireless modem, Youtube seem to work for a while in the "problematic" computer.  However, this is not sustainable.  I have a 2.4GHz cordless phone in my home.  Not sure whether this contributes to anything.  However this does not impact the other laptop. The working laptop is having Intel WiFi link 5100 AGN

Comment: Are they playing at the same time?

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing the channels but not much improvement

Comment: What wireless card/chipset/driver do you have on the laptop with the problems? What about on the one that works fine?

Comment: @Raj register your account, that way you don't have to edit it like this.

Comment: @Raj I think you gave us the chipset that works, but it doesn't look like you gave us the chipset that fails.

Comment: The wireless in the computer that does not work is Intel/PRO Wireless 3945 ABG Network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the frequency of the router. It'll be in the router config. Otherwise, try moving closer. These are a bit difficult to diagnose sometimes, but it's a problem with the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably reduced the wireless speed without reducing your internet speed.  By enforcing say 5 or 11 Mbps instead of having it adjust automatically (usually to highest available) you can both increase speed and reduce packet droppage/garbleage.  However if the problem doesn't also occur on other websites (e.g. Vimeo) then it can't be the wireless link that causes this.  Perhaps YouTube updated their code without properly supporting your browser/browsing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the 802.11n features of the router. It claims to have "some N features", but it was not able to pass Wi-Fi certification for 802.11n, which means its N support is probably terribly crappy (Wi-Fi certification sets a really low bar, so if an AP can't even pass that, it probably sucks).